# How to use shared Swift static library in other Swift static libraries

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am experimenting using Swift static libraries for an iOS app.

This works if the app links to static libraries, as long as there are no cross-dependencies between the libraries.

Where I am having some issues, is when using static libraries from other static libraries. For example, there is a static library with general purpose code, which is used by higher level libraries and the app:

- Utilities (shared library)
- Database (depends on Utilities)
- Network (depends on Utilities)
- App (depends on Database, Network, and Utilities)

In an Objective-C or C code base, it would be possible to set the header include path, and link the shared library in the app. Is there an equivalent procedure in Swift?

This is using Swift 4, and Xcode 9.2.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Sort of. I added all the static libs to "Link binary with libraries" under "Build phases" for the main app project (with status set to "Required" for each lib). This didn't work right away. I also had to add each of the dependency libs to "Link binary with libraries" for each static lib project, setting status to "Optional". This worked for a while until one day Xcode complained about duplicate symbols. I removed the dependencies from "Link binary with libraries" for each static lib, and it carried on working. it sometimes randomly breaks and I fiddle with "Link binary with libraries".